# Changing python/python3 symbolic links breaks paths, and breaks pip/pip3

Tags: python, pip, symlink

My Ubuntu 20.04.6 has python3.8 installed. pip is the following version `pip 23.3.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`. I needed python3.9. So I installed python3.9.
I then changed python/python symbolic links to this

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
```

Then, for my project I did a `pip install .`, this worked and all packages installed.
However after that was complete, pip broke. I can no longer run any pip/pip3 commands.

I get the following error. Which I know is misleading.

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1553, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1571, in X509StoreFlags
    NOTIFY_POLICY = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY'
```

Also I noticed that if I log out and log back in I see the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo", line 22, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[1:], reactor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 115, in run
    for plugin in config.get_plugins():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 69, in get_plugins
    return [namedClass("landscape.sysinfo.%s.%s"
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
    return [namedClass("landscape.sysinfo.%s.%s"
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 173, in namedObject
    module = namedModule('.'.join(classSplit[:-1]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 159, in namedModule
    topLevel = __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/network.py", line 4, in <module>
    from netifaces import AF_INET, AF_INET6
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'
```

This is probably associated to my some calls in my `.bashrc`.

If I change all the symbolic links back to python3.8 like the following, everything goes back to normal.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```

Note: I do not have internet or access to the outside world on this host. So I cannot download anything. I have seen posts recommending using `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`, but I cannot do that.

How can I troubleshoot / fix this problem so python/python3 are using python3.9 and pip/pip3 still works?